# SpriteKit Objective-C: A touchesBegan() on an SKSpriteNode class instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skspritenode, touchesbegan

I have a reference to my class called TBButton. The TBButton is a subclass is SKSpriteNode, and has an enum with several types (one being "Blue"). How would I create a touchesBegan() function that gets called when any instance of that TBButton class gets touched? I've tried implementing a very simple touchesBegan() with an NSLog() inside the TBButton class itself, but that didn't work. I've also tried finding if the touched button in the GameScene.m is an instance of TBButton with this code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
        TBButton *touchedNode = (TBButton *)[self nodeAtPoint:location];

        if (touchedNode && [touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"button"]) {

            if (touchedNode.type == Blue) {

                // Touched a blue button.
                NSLog(@"Touched a blue button");
                /// Find out how to do this code! It ain't workin!

            }

        }

    }
}
```

That was the code I tried inside my GameScene.m, but that didn't log anything to the console when I'd touch one of my buttons. Yes, I have made sure that the name of the TBButton instance was @"button", so that's not the problem.

To make things easier on me, please ignore any code inside the GameScene.m if that's not necessary. What I'm really wondering is if I can somehow implement a touchesBegan() function inside my TBButton.m itself! Or can I not? Would putting an instance method inside TBButton.h, setting it up to do the code when the button is touched in TBButton.m, and calling it when its instance inside GameScene.m work?

Hopefully you understand my question!

Comment: Have you set `userInteractionEnabled` to YES? It is the "Boolean value that indicates whether the node receives touch events".

Comment: Yes, I have. Although that's the default value, anyway.

Comment: Ah, yes, for SKSpriteNode it is (which I just read you are using). For SKNode it isn't, though!

Answer (score 0):

I gather your main issue is one of identification. SKSpriteNode being a subclass of SKNode you have 2 easy options:

When you create an instance of TBButton set the name property to something like "TBButton". You can then check for the node's name in the touchesBegan method.

```
if([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"TBButton"]) {
    //....
}
```

If you require more than just a simple string, you can use the userData property of SKNode. Again, when creating an instance of TBButton:

```
self.userData = [NSMutableDictionary new];
[self.userData setObject:@"GreenButton" forKey:@"ButtonColor"];
```

Checking in touchesBegan would look something like this:

```
if([[touchedNode.userData objectForKey:@"ButtonColor"]isEqualToString:@"GreenButton"]) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: I see where you're going there, sangony, but that doesn't work, either. No errors are thrown up, or anything, but nothing happens. I implemented your code by setting the object of the NSMutableArray when the case of Green is brought up in TBButton.m. I have an 'enum' with a few cases, and in case Green, I added the line to 'setObject'. I tried using your if-statement in the GameScene.m. It didn't work, sadly.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I figured it out on my own, everyone! But thanks for the help. The problem was that in my TBButton class, I forgot to set the class' ButtonType to be the property.

Here's the line of code I added to TBButton.m:

```
    if (self) {
        self.type = type;
    }
```

So, I hope that this "conversation" isn't going to downgrade me, or something. I still appreciate your answers, though. Thanks!